Unable to Use Parameters from One Child Generator in Another within ArgoCD ApplicationSet
I'm trying to deploy multiple operators as ArgoCD applications across all clusters, with the flexibility to skip deployment of certain operators in specific clusters. To achieve this, I've set up an ArgoCD ApplicationSet with a matrix generator, as shown below:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: core-operators
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  goTemplate: true
  goTemplateOptions: ["missingkey=error"]
  generators:
    - matrix:
        generators:
          - merge:
              mergeKeys: 
                - server
              generators:
                - clusters: {}
                - list:
                    elements:
                      - server: '{{.server}}'
                        clusterName: '{{.name}}'
                        enableMetricsServer: true
                        enablePrometheus: true
                      - server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
                        clusterName: in-cluster
                        enableMetricsServer: true
                        enablePrometheus: false
          - list:
              elements:
                - operatorName: metrics-server
                  namespace: monitoring
                  enable: '{{.enableMetricsServer}}'
                - operatorName: prometheus
                  namespace: monitoring
                  enable: '{{.enablePrometheus}}'
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{.name}}-{{.operatorName}}-{{.enable}}'
      annotations:
        argocd.argoproj.io/manifest-generate-paths: ".;.."
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: git@github.com/operators.git
        targetRevision: HEAD
        path: null-deployment
      destination:
        server: '{{.server}}'
        namespace: '{{.namespace}}'
      syncPolicy:
        syncOptions:
          - CreateNamespace=true
          - ServerSideApply=true
          - Replace=true
          - Force=true
        retry:
          limit: 2
  templatePatch: |
    {{- if eq .enable "true" }}
    spec:
      source:
        repoURL: git@github.com/operators.git
        targetRevision: HEAD
        path: {{.operatorName}}
        helm:
          releaseName: "{{.operatorName}}-parent"
          values: |
            clusterName: {{.name}}
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: true
    {{- end }}

However, when applying this ApplicationSet, I encounter the following error:
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2024-07-31T05:22:57Z
    Message:               failed to get params for second generator in the matrix generator: child generator returned an error on parameter generation: failed to replace parameters in generator: failed to deeply replace JSON field contents: failed to execute go template {{.enableMetricsServer}}: template: :1:2: executing "" at <.enableMetricsServer>: map has no entry for key "enableMetricsServer"
    Reason:                ApplicationGenerationFromParamsError
    Status:                True
    Type:                  ErrorOccurred
    Last Transition Time:  2024-07-31T05:22:57Z
    Message:               failed to get params for second generator in the matrix generator: child generator returned an error on parameter generation: failed to replace parameters in generator: failed to deeply replace JSON field contents: failed to execute go template {{.enableMetricsServer}}: template: :1:2: executing "" at <.enableMetricsServer>: map has no entry for key "enableMetricsServer"
    Reason:                ErrorOccurred
    Status:                False
    Type:                  ParametersGenerated
    Last Transition Time:  2024-07-31T05:22:57Z
    Message:               failed to get params for second generator in the matrix generator: child generator returned an error on parameter generation: failed to replace parameters in generator: failed to deeply replace JSON field contents: failed to execute go template {{.enableMetricsServer}}: template: :1:2: executing "" at <.enableMetricsServer>: map has no entry for key "enableMetricsServer"
    Reason:                ApplicationGenerationFromParamsError
    Status:                False
    Type:                  ResourcesUpToDate

I came across this closed issue on GitHub, which suggests that this problem has been fixed, but I still encounter the error. Am I missing something in the configuration, or is there another workaround I should consider?
ArgoCD Slack conversation link: https://cloud-native.slack.com/archives/C01U45M2SVB/p1722362317180959?thread_ts=1722277849.358909&cid=C01U45M2SVB
Details:
ArgoCD version: v2.11.7
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!
